# Batch "For" loop outputs in two lines instead of one in TXT

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want this following for-loop to output the findings of these two searches in one line in the All_Metadata.txt

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    findstr /B "589" %%a
    findstr /X /C:"1 1,96 " %%a
    ) >> All_Metadata.txt
```

This For-Loop output looks like this:

```
58998545
1 1,96
```

Instead of (this is what it should look like):

```
58998545 1 1,96
```

Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide some sample date of an input text file…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the output of the both `findstr` commands into variables with  `for /f` loops and `echo` them together (no need for a variable with the second one; just use the `for` variable):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set "b="
    set "c="
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /B "589" "%%a"') do set "b=%%b"
    for /f "delims=" %%c in ('findstr /i /X /C:"1 1,96 " "%%a"') do set "c=%%c"
    echo(!b! !c!
)
```

Another way is, to use the `set /p` trick to write the first `findstr` result without a line feed and just add the result from the second `findstr` (doesn't need delayed expansion):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set "b="
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /B "589" "%%a"') do <nul set /p "=%%b "
    findstr /i /X /C:"1 1,96 " "%%a"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and extensive help! You saved me.